# Simple Javascript date conversion

Tags: javascript, date

I have this - `Tue, 03 Apr 2012 05:00:33 GMT`

Need this - `20120323111106`

Google has failed me, I think I just don't know exactly what im searching for so I kept it simple here with the question.

EDIT: The dates do not match obviously, just looking to get it in that format.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573581/javascript-string-to-date-conversion-simple

Comment: There is also this new js library for working with date: [XDate](http://arshaw.com/xdate/)

Comment: "Tue, 03 Apr 2012 05:00:33 GMT" and "20120323111106" aren't even the same date. Do you just need it in that format, or is the later supposed to be the actual generated string given the input date

Comment: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 1):

Good answer (later edited):

I think this is what you are looking for :

```
function addZero(val){
    if (parseInt(val) < 10) return "0" + val;
    return val;
}

var dt = new Date("Tue, 03 Apr 2012 05:00:33 GMT");
console.log(dt.getFullYear() + addZero(dt.getMonth()) + addZero(dt.getDay()) + addZero(dt.getHours()) + addZero(dt.getMinutes()) + addZero(dt.getSeconds()))
```

Initial wrong answer :

```
var dt = new Date("Tue, 03 Apr 2012 05:00:33 GMT")
var miliseconds = dt.getTime();
```

I've tested it and my computer converted it automatically to GMT +3 (my timezone), you can play with that according to your timezone.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't provide the output im looking for. This just gives me the date in milliseconds.

Comment: oh, I was having the impression that the long string is the milliseconds date format. Sorry!

Comment: I wish, that would be easy :)

Answer (score 0):

Writing a function to parse a string should work for you. By the looks of it, any date string that you currently have will be the same length. If this is the case this should be relatively easy. Just make sure your strings are in this format before you pass them in as arguments.

```
function parse(string) {
    var out = "yyyymmddhhmmss"
    out.charAt(0) = string.charAt(13);
    out.charAt(1) = string.charAt(14);
    out.charAt(2) = string.charAt(15);
    out.charAt(3) = string.charAt(16);

    //if else statements for each month converting to numbers
    if (string.substring(9,12).equals("Apr")) {
         out.charAt(4) = '0';
         out.charAt(5) = '4';
    }

    out.charAt(6) = string.charAt(18);
    out.charAt(7) = string.charAt(19);

    ...etc for the remaining values

    return out
}
```

My numbers for character indices may be off, but if you use this idea, it should set you straight. Define a function and pass in the dates in the format you have, and out will come the dates in the format you want.